# Arrays inside objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to create an object that inside him have some fields, one of them supposed to be an array.
var ob=
{
      name : "asdad"
      array ?
}
But I dont know how to.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: var ob= { name : "asdad", arr: [1,2,3,4] }. a simple google search would have brought this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a value is just a value, whether it be a simple scalar or a complicated looking object.

```
var obj = {
    name: "user name",
    stocks: ["AAPL", "GOOG"],
    cars: [ {make:"Honda", model: "accord"},
            {make:"BMW", model: "525", year: 2014}
          ]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
var ob= { 
  name : "asdad",
  myArray : ["value1", "value2", "etc."]
}
```

It would be helpful for you to go over [this MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).